# How do I modify the VS Code HTML formatter?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Currently trying to write some HTML for something. VS Code did an update yesterday and now the auto-formatter (`Alt+Shift+F`) is a different set of options and is overriding everything.

How do I access that specifical file to modify it. I currently have "Prettier" installed but it does not handle HTML

Answer (score 10):

Right-click in your text editing area and choose `Format Document With...`. A popup will appear on top then choose `Choose default formatter` and then choose `Prettier`

Answer (score 1):

- You can trigger suggestions at any time by pressing `Ctrl+Space`.
- To improve the formatting of your HTML source code, you can use the
  Format Document command `Ctrl+Shift+I` to format the entire file or
  Format Selection `Ctrl+K` `Ctrl+F` to just format the selected text.

Read this: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the formatting using the settings `html.format.[...]`, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/html#_formatting

Answer (score 0):

I love using `Shift + Option + F` on my Mac to clean up my HTML code. It's like hitting a magic button.

Also right-clicking on the text, and then using `Format Document with`

> HTML Language Features

formats are a little bit different. You can always modify and improve it as you like.